# Practice with templates returning error

Tags: c++

The code is working in that it `couts` `haha` but it causes an error because it says:

`Process returned -1073741819 <0xC0000005>`

And a window pops up telling me if I would like to send an error message. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class A>

    A print( A a ) {
        cout << a;
    }

template <class T>

    class David {
        T a;
        public:
            David( T something ) : a( something ) {}
            void laugh() {
                print(a);
            }
    };

int main() {

    David <string> Do("Hahaha");

    Do.laugh();

}
```

Comment: Please turn on (and look at) your compiler's warnings. You wouldn't have needed to post here if you had.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? I don't see how this compiled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template <class A>

    A print( A a ) {
        cout << a;
    }
```

It`s incorrect. No return value in function, so, compiler returns some garbage from stack.
And better i think will be this declaration

```
template<class A>
void print(const A& a) { cout << a; }
```

Comment: I thank-eth thou. Thine answer wilst be accepted in the coming time.

Comment: May I ask what the `const A& a` is and what it does?

Comment: const-reference to A, when you use void print(A a) copy-ctor will be called, when you pass by const-reference copy-ctor will not be called (it doesn`t matter when you work with primitive types, but for example std::string is not primitive, so it`s better to use const reference), also you can`t change data that a refers.